# DOT Numbers: 0 or O?

Tags: tires

In DOT numbers how can I tell the difference between 0 (zero) and O (capital o)? Most fonts used on tire sidewalls make them difficult to tell apart, and I can't find any rules online saying that capital O's aren't used, so I'm left to guess on a case-by-case basis. I know the last four digits are numbers-only because they tell when the tire was manufactured, but on all tires I've seen any zeros in the last four digits are indistinguishable from the capital O in "DOT".

It's very important to keep accurate record of DOT numbers in my line of work (winter tire traction testing), but unfortunately I haven't been able to find anyone who can really help me with this issue.

Also sorry if this isn't the right forum for this question, it was the first forum I found where I thought people might know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The last four digits are the age information and are only numbers.

> "I know the last four digits are numbers-only because they tell when
>   the tire was manufactured, but on all tires I've seen any zeros in the
>   last four digits are indistinguishable from the capital O in "DOT"

(*I cannot digest that statement, if you know the last 4 are numbers only then you do not need to distinguish, you already know.*)

The following is  quote from [Tirerack.com](https://blog.tirerack.com/blog/colintirerackcom/how-old-are-my-tires-and-how-long-will-they-last)

> The way to determine the age of a tire is easy once you know what to
>   look for. Every tire has an identification number starting with "DOT",
>   followed by a series of numbers and letters with the last four numbers
>   identifying the tire's age. The last two are the production year,
>   while the first two identify the week in which the tire was made. In
>   the picture below, the sequence ends in "5107", which shows the tire
>   was produced in the 51st week of 2007.

( despite my instance that i know everything, i do not in fact know everything. )